# Always aws opensearch maximum memory utilization is about 99%

Tags: opensearch

Currently, I used AWS OpenSearch cluster. Cluster configuration follow above

- Control Plane: r5.2xlarge * 3
- Data Plane: r5.2xlarge * 5

cluster Maximum cpu utilization is 10~15%, but maximum memory utilization is 99%

I'm trying to scale down the data nodes in this cluster, but it's messing me up because it says it's using 99% of the memory.
But something tells me that this 99% is not all being used.
Can anyone tell me what this 99% means, and is it okay to scale down?